# IntelliJ IDEA's "Type mismatch in 'any' type" is getting triggered even it should not

Tags: javascript, typescript, intellij-idea, socket.io

I am developing an Node.JS application in TypeScript that is using Socket.IO v4 server and I found weird issue. IntelliJ IDEA has this inspection:

[image]

and it is getting triggered when I beleive it should not be triggered.

Example:

```js
import { Server as SocketServer } from 'socket.io'

interface ServerToClientEvents {
    'test': (data: { foo: boolean, bar: boolean }) => void;
}

type ClientToServerEvents = {
    // NOT IMPORTANT
}

interface SocketData {
    // NOT IMPORTANT
}

const httpServer = // Express http server, not important
const socketServer = new SocketServer<ClientToServerEvents, ServerToClientEvents, never, SocketData>(httpServer)

socketServer.emit("gamemodes status ping", {
        foo: true,
        bar: true
    })
```

The typechecking is correctly throwing an error if the event name, or data type is not valid:

[image]
[image]

but it is also throwing an warning that (I believe) should not happen:

[image]

First, I just planned to disable the inspection, but I think I should first understand why IDE thinks that this is not valid.

Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately I failed to reproduce the issue using your example. Anyway, disabling the inspection is a right solution,it's off by default.